# Random access to specified record within CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, random-access

This code works fine:

```
            string[] lineOfContents = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\users.csv");
            foreach (var line in lineOfContents)
            {
                string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
                if (tokens[2] == "ed@yahoo.com")
                {                    
                    MessageBox.Show("Email already exists");
                }
               else
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("Ok");
               }
            }
```

Above code works like this:
[image]

So, I'd like to have simple code to do "Direct access" to the "Email" record within CSV file, like this:
[image]

Comment: The only way to "find" an arbitrary value is to process all records/data until a match is found. Unlike a proper SQL engine, CSV does not have any intrinsic "index" support; while a binary-search can be done on a sorted column (like the ID), doing so is more complex, requires ordering, and likely won't make a difference.

Comment: @CrownFord - reading this question, the solutions, and your comments, you have to understand that what you want is not possible.  There is no "search" mechanism that will parse a text file without looping or reading the entire file into memory (a csv is not SQL). Word and Excel (multi-billion dollar software) have to have the file loaded into memory before a Ctrl+F works.

Comment: @Tommy if we understand the concept of DB engine, we will find it possible. I'm new in c# development field :)

Comment: I get what you are saying, but you must realize that a DB is a single file (usually) with pages, indexes and an underlying engine based on relational calculus that provides the sweet, relational goodness that is SQL.  A csv is simply a bunch of blocks of bytes on the hard drive, maybe in sequential order, maybe not.  Each block contains random bits of the file and as a result, it is literally impossible to scan the contents without loading the file.

Comment: I think I'll go for [cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org) as big text file database as final solution :)

Comment: So, you are going to implement an Apache based (nothing against Apache - but when you are using .NET, there are more "compatible" tool sets), large enterprise scale solution on a Windows server when you could simply use SqlExpress or LocalDB, import your CSV into one of those solutions, both fully supported out of the box with C#/.NET using Entity Framework or ADO.NET?  I wish you the best of luck in your endeavors... :/

Comment: @Tommy, I will take your advice. Thanx :)

Answer (score 5):

```
string fileContents = File.ReadAllText("c:\\users.csv");

if (fileContents.Contains("ed@yahoo.com")) {
    MessageBox.Show("Email already exists");
} else {
    MessageBox.Show("Ok");
}
```

Comment: I also thought that text search makes the most sense in this case. The time spent parsing file into a searchable data structure would be far longer than just a simple text search.

Comment: @digthewells, thanx...I'm dreaming to have kind of magic...I don't want to read all lines, I want to read "Email" col only and do searching there. Is this possible :) –  CrownFord 11 mins ago

Comment: I don't see how you are going to get around reading all file contents because any tool you use is still going to have to read the data into some structure so you can just look at the email column.  right now there are no columns.  CSV is not like a database.  I think this is your most efficient solution.  Put all of your email addresses in an array and loop through them checking if they are contained in the string.  It will never fail because there is a comma on both sides.  You won't see a noticeable speed difference if you have 100 or 1000 lines in your CSV reading the text.

Answer (score 1):

One way can be:

```
string[] lineOfContents = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\users.csv");
string email="ed@yahoo.com";
if (lineOfContents.Contains(email))
{  
    MessageBox.Show("Email already exists");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ok");
}
```

Other way using `linq` can be :

```
string[] lineOfContents = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\users.csv");
string email="ed@yahoo.com";
if(lineOfContents.Any(e->e.Contains(email))){...}
```

One more :

```
string temp = "";
if(String.Join(temp,lineOfContents).Contains(email);
```

Another One OR **BEST** can be:

```
if (Array.IndexOf(lineOfContents, email) >= 0)
{
    //Your stuff goes here
}
```

I am afraid, what you're asking("..Is it possible to avoid reading all file contents, I prefer to go to "Email" directly") is not possible out of box. But there are some good utilities that can help you to do more efficiently(but I doubt they don't parse the file).

Some good ones are :

- [**A Fast CSV Reader**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader)
- [**CsvHelper**](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) (Nuget package)
- Another good one from Microsoft is [**TextFieldParser Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx).

  - The `TextFieldParser` object provides methods and properties for parsing structured text files. Parsing a text file with the `TextFieldParser` is similar to iterating over a text file, while the `ReadFields` method to extract fields of text is similar to splitting the strings.

    The TextFieldParser can parse two types of files: **delimited** or **fixed-width**. Some properties, such as Delimiters and HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes are meaningful only when working with delimited files, while the FieldWidths property is meaningful only when working with fixed-width files.

Comment: thanx...Is it possible to avoid reading all file contents, I prefer to go to "Email" directly :) –  CrownFord 9 mins ago